# I have 2 different lists I want to style on css, how I should do it?

Tags: html, css

**HTML**

```
<pre>

<head>
    <title>
        title of the page
    </title>
    <link rel="styleheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css"> 
</head>
<body>
<ul>
    <li>Italy</li>
    <li>France</li>
    <li>Greece</li>
</ul>
   <h1> This is the main heading</h1>
  <p>This text might be an introduction to the rest of
the page. And if the page is a long one it might
be split up into several sub-headings</p>
<h2>this is the second heading</h2>
<p> long live the King :Many long articles have sub-headings so to help
you follow the structure of what is being written.
There may even be sub-sub-headings (or lower-level
headings).</p>
<h2>Another sub heading</h2>
<p>Here you can see another sub-heading.</p>
<p>This is how we make a word appear <b>bold.</b></p>
<p>This is how we make a word appear <i>italic</i>.
</p>
<ul>
    <li>Potatoes</li>
    <li>Oranges</li>
    <li>Berries</li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
</pre>
```

**CSS:**

```
<pre>
body{background: url("../img/poza.jpg");

}
ul{text-align: left;

}
ol{
    list-style-position: right;
    text-align: 
}
</pre>
```

Comment: define 2 different classes that apply to the lists.

Comment: Use classes, ID's, or `:nth-child` http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NdvQYL

Answer (score 1):

Use classes or id's

HTML

```
<ul class="list1">
    <li>Italy</li>
    <li>France</li>
    <li>Greece</li>
</ul>

<ul class="list2">
    <li>Potatoes</li>
    <li>Oranges</li>
    <li>Berries</li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
.list1 {
   text-align: left;
   color: red;
}
.list2 {
   text-align: right;
   color: blue;
}
```

Also if you want to apply CSS to all 'li' inside for example the 'ul class="list1"' (to avoid giving class to every 'li' element) you can do it with child/parent in css:

```
.list1 > li {
   color: orange;
}
```